# Tkinter Python: Grid &Entry problem. How to add and remove dynamicly Entry&delete Button wingets

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

Hi im trying to write simple app with posibility to add and delete Entry boxes and i cant get the expected result.
What i want : add button add a row with entry and delete this entry button
[image]

what i get :Entry is not created and delete button is not his column
[image]

here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.all_entries = []

        self.addboxButton = Button(root, text='<Add >', command=self.addBox)
        self.addboxButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.rows =[]
    def addBox(self):
        print ("ADD")
        new_row = Row(self,root)
        self.rows.append(new_row)
        self.render()
    def render(self):
        for i in range(len(self.rows)):
            self.rows[i].grid(row=i + 1, column=1, sticky=W,columnspan=2, padx=(5, 0), pady=(5, 0))  
class Row(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, main_frame, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__()
        self.main_frame = main_frame
        
        self.entryRowVar = StringVar()
        self.entryRow= Entry(self.main_frame, textvariable=self.entryRowVar)
        self.entryRow.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W,)
        self.del_btn = Button(self, text='Delete') 
        self.del_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W,)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The parent of the `Entry` should be `self` instead of `self.main_frame`.

Answer (score 0):

> What i want : add button add a row with entry and delete this entry
> button

@acw1668 mentioned in comment by using `self` instead of `self.main_frame` on line 26.

```
self.entryRow= Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryRowVar)
```

Secondly, you want exactly the first image, not the second image. Can be fixed.

On line 19, Change this:

```
self.rows[i].grid(row=i+1, ...)
```

to:

```
self.rows[i].grid(row=i, ...) #remove +1
```

Execute the script and you will get exactly on the first image.

[image]